# polkit asks for password constantly while looking at wifi settings

Tags: network-manager, policykit

polkit asks for my password when I do ANYTHING with wifi settings. I've already tried editing usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.policy and setting allow_active to yet, but it seems to revert at apt update or something. I don't know it's super annoying.

Comment: I thought I'd solved the problem by editing /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/10-network-manager.pkla, but I just got prompted again.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I got into this situation be either setting up xrdp or more likely Chrome Remote Desktop as that package is a poorly maintained mess. I just re-installed it the other day and had to re-install Ubuntu because it did this again.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me!
Create a new file and name it: **10-network-manager.pkla**
Copy and paste these lines inside the file.

```
[Let user thaki modify system settings for network]
Identity=unix-user:[YOUR_USER_NAME]
Action=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.system
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=yes
```

Note: replace [YOUR_USER_NAME] with your current username.
Now, you need to copy this file to

```
/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/
```

You may need to restart or log out.

Hope this will solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have this problem anymore so I can't really test it, see my above comment about Chrome Remote Desktop